# SoundCloud: API key in client-side script

Tags: client-side, soundcloud, api-key

The SoundCloud API docs (http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/sdks#javascript) suggest to provide our client_id in the client-side code:

> To start using the SDK just add this script to your HTML and
>   initialize the client with your own client_id and optionally your
>   redirect_uri in case you want to use authentication:

```
<script src="//connect.soundcloud.com/sdk.js"></script>
<script>
  SC.initialize({
    client_id: "YOUR_CLIENT_ID",
    redirect_uri: "http://example.com/callback.html",
  });
</script>
```

If we expose our client_id as suggested, it can be easily added to requests made by other apps.
Is it still secure to do so?
Isn't our app going to be rate limited if some other app sends too many requests using our client_id?